# Accessing JSON attributes within Jade Mixins

Tags: json, pug, mixins, javascript-objects

## Motivation

I have some ugly working code embedded in my Jade template and I want to move it to a mixin so it is more readable, maintainable, etc.

## The code

A simplified equivalent version of the mixing would be:

```
mixin mixinName(param1, param2, paramObject)
    .tile(class="#{param1 >= paramObject['atr1'] && param1 < paramObject['atr1'] + paramObject['atr2'])?'additionalClass':''"}) &nbsp;
```

### Why do I think this should work?

If instead of `&nbsp;` I put `paramObject` I get the object contents in the HTML like `{atr1: 2, atr2: 2}`, so they are there. If I instead put `paramObject['atr1']` or `paramObject.atr1`, etc. I only get a blank space. My guess is I am not accessing the attributes properly.

### The jade code context

I think it is not needed but here it is.

```
...
template(repeat="{{col in columns | enumerate}}")
    .col
        template(repeat="{{tile in col.value | enumerate}}")
            +mixinName("{{col.index}}", "{{tile.index}}", "{{cursor}}")
...
```

## Ugly workaround solution

I think this is ugly because I really have many more params, and many more attributes/fields I need to compare within the paramObject, so it just clutters the rest of the Jade template.

```
mixin mixinName(param1, param2, paramObjectAtr1, paramObjectAtr2)
    .tile(class="#{param1 >= paramObjectAtr1 && param1 < paramObjectAtr1 + paramObjectAtr2)?'additionalClass':''"}) &nbsp;
```

### The jade code context

Basically the same as before, but sending each object parameter as a different parameter.

```
...
template(repeat="{{col in columns | enumerate}}")
    .col
        template(repeat="{{tile in col.value | enumerate}}")
            +mixinName("{{col.index}}", "{{tile.index}}", "{{cursor['atr1']}}", "{{cursor['atr2']}}")
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange that `paramObject` works in place of `&nbsp`. Jade syntax should be:

```
.tile(...)= paramObject
```

or

```
.tile(...) #{paramObject}
```

If you just use space after the tag or class name, Jade thinks you mean plain text, not JS code.

As for your mixin, you can go:

```
mixin mixinName(param1, param2, paramObject)
  - var moarClasses = [];
  - if (param1 >= paramObject.atr1 &&
  -     param1 < paramObject.atr1 + paramObject.atr2)
  -   moarClasses.push('additionalClass');

  .tile(class=moarClasses)= paramObject.atr3
```

Comment: Might not be correct syntax, but in the last line of the mixin, this would happen to me:

1 `.tile(class=moarClasses) {{cursor['atr1']}}` returns the expected result, i.e. the content of atr1 belonging to cursor.

2 `.tile(class=moarClasses)= cursor['atr1']` or `.tile(class=moarClasses) #{cursor['atr1']}` the tile appears empty.

3 Changing `cursor['atr1']` for `cursor.atr1` in first case gives a runtime error. In second they show the same behaviour.

And the case which works is because it is using `cursor` defined as a global, not the mixin parameter (I named it cursor instead of paramObject)

Comment: Thanks for your answer anyway, I marked as accepted as I think the `moarClasses` idea was helpful. I still have not managed to make the conditional (or the ugly `a?b:c`) work after many variations and spending several more hours at it, so I will use some workaround and get going (different than the one I mentioned in my question).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.All in all, my suspicion that your problem may lay outside of Jade only grows. Because [here's a pen](http://codepen.io/hoichi/pen/GJjJNL) in pure Jade where Jade syntax, be it `.tile()= cursor.atr3` or `.tile() #{cursor.atr3}` obviously works, and your Mustache-style syntax obviously doesn't. Which means that in your case, _mustache replacements are done by something else_. What else does that _something else_ interfere in, I've no idea.